# modeling a set S as a mixed integer linear programming problem

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

This is actually a homework question and I am very much stumped. I have to model the following set as an MILP

S = {x,y∈R| |x| + |y|  = 1}

There is no need for an objective function but an arbitrary one can be included

Answer (score 2):

I don´t see from this single constraint, that it is a MILP or can be transformed into one. But you can remove the absolute value signs.

Let´s define $x=x^+-x^-$, where $x^+,x^- \geq 0$

Then $|x|=x^++x^-$

Similar transformation for $y$. In total you get

$x^++x^- + y^++y^-  = 1$

$x^+,x^- , y^+,y^- \geq 0$

This could be a part of the standard form of a  $\text{linear program (LP)}$.

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm afraid. Suppose $|x|+|y|<1$. Then I can make $x^++x_-+y^++y_-=1$ by adding an appropriate value to each of these four variables.

Comment: If you have a min/max problem and an optimal solution at least one of the variables $x^+, x^-$ become zero. Similar for $y^+,y^-$

Comment: That's true, but we don't have that guarantee here.

Comment: Yes it can be guaranteed without any additional restrictions. I saw a proof somewhere but I have to search it. But if you have $max \ 2|x|+3|y|$ it would not make sense, that one of the adjusted x-variables or adjusted y-variables is not zero. Otherwise $|x|$ or $|y|$ wouldn´t be maximum.  $x^+$ and $x^-$ must not (partially) neutralize  each other.

Comment: The point is that you can't be sure that $x$ or $y$ are even in the objective.

Comment: You've converted a non-convex constraint $|x|+|y|=1$ into the intersection of convex constraints. Surely you see that can't be equivalent, even if we don't have an explicit counterexample in front of us.

Comment: But I think you will not find an example, where my transformation does not lead to an optimal solution, if an optimal solution exists.

Comment: I do admit I'm having trouble finding one but I am certain it's possible. I'll let you know if I do.

Comment: I do admit, that it is difficult to find such an example. In your example $\text{min}\ \ 3|x|+|y|, |x|+|y|=1$ it is obvious, that either $y^+$ or $y^-$ is zero,

Comment: I now agree with you that in a simple case where this is the only constraint and the objective is linear, this convex relaxation will work. What concerns me is a situation where the other variables, constraints, and objectives would place the optimal solution strictly within the $|x|+|y|<1$ region.

Answer (score 2):

Think of what $S$ represents graphically: the lines of a square with corners at (-1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,-1), so you can write $S$ as follows:

$$S=\{y= 1-x, 0\le x \le 1,0\le y \le 1 \}\cup\{y= x+1,-1\le x \le 0,0\le y \le 1\}\cup\{y= -1+x,0\le x \le 1,-1\le y \le 0 \}\cup \{ y= -x-1,-1\le x \le 0,-1\le y \le 0  \}$$

Now introduce boolean variables to decide on which line you want to be: let $w_i =1$ if and only if you are on line $i$, $i=1,…,4$, let $M$ be a very large integer, and add the following (disjunctive) constraints:

$$x+y\le 1 + M(1-\omega_1)\quad \quad x+y\ge 1 -M(1-\omega_1)$$
$$x-y\le 1 + M(1-\omega_2)\quad \quad x-y\ge 1 -M(1-\omega_2)$$
$$-x+y\le 1 + M(1-\omega_3)\quad \quad -x+y\ge 1 -M(1-\omega_3)$$
$$-x-y\le 1 + M(1-\omega_4)\quad \quad -x-y\ge 1 -M(1-\omega_4)$$

Now to make sure you are on exactly one of the sides of the square, add:

$$ \omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3+\omega_4=1$$

Depending on what your objective function is, you might have to adjust this last constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Kuifje is on the right track, but it's not quite there. It's true that $|x|+|y|=1$ can be expressed as $|x|+|y|\leq 1$ and $|x|+|y|\geq 1$.

The first of these is convex so we don't need to do anything special convert it to linear inequalities. There are a variety of ways to do this but let's do it this way:
$$x+y\leq 1, \quad -x+y\leq 1, \quad x-y\leq 1, \quad -x-y\leq 1$$
Now for $|x|+|y|\geq 1$ which is not convex. Let's express it as 
$$x+y\geq 1 ~~\text{or}~~ -x+y\geq 1 ~~\text{or}~~ x-y\geq 1 ~~\text{or}~~ -x-y\geq 1$$
This is where Kuifje was going. Introduce binary variables $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ and do this:
$$x+y\geq 1-2w_1 ~~\text{or}~~ -x+y\geq 1-2w_2 ~~\text{or}~~ x-y\geq 1-2w_3 ~~\text{or}~~ -x-y\geq 1-2w_4$$
Consider what happens when $w_1=1$, then we have $x+y\geq -1$. But this is equivalent to $-x-y\leq 1$, which is identical to the constraint above. So when $w_1=1$, that first constraint is effectively removed. A similar argument is true when $w_2$, $w_3$, or $w_4$ is 1.

However, we don't want $w_1=w_2=w_3=w_4=1$, because then all *four* of those constraints would be disabled, and to satisfy our disjunction we need at least one of them active. So we need to add this:
$$w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4\leq 3.$$
In summary, our constraints are
$$1-2w_1 \leq +x + y \leq 1$$
$$1-2w_2 \leq -x+y \leq 1$$
$$1-2w_3 \leq +x-y \leq 1$$
$$1-2w_4 \leq -x-y \leq 1$$
$$w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4\leq 3, \quad w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\in\{0,1\}$$
This is the closest I could come to Kuifje's method. But if we had $n$ variables here instead of $2$, this wouldn't be the best approach, because it would end up creating $2^n$ constraints and $2^n$ new variables. Suppose we want to implement the constraint $\|x\|_1 = \sum_i|x_i|= 1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Our first step is to create a new variable $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and define:
$$|x_i|=y_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n, \quad \sum_i y_i = 1.$$
Then we use a technique similar to the above to convert $|x_i|=y_i$. Defining $w\in\{0,1\}^n$, we create these constraints:
$$-y_i \leq x_i \leq y_i,~~x_i\geq y_i-2w_i,~~-x_i\geq y_i-2(1-w_i), \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$
If $w_i=0$, we have $x_i=y_i$, and if $w_i=1$, we have $-x_i=y_i$. Since $y_i\geq 0$ is implied by the first pair of inequalities, it must be the case that $|x_i|=y_i$.
So we have $4n+1$ inequalities and $2n$ new variables. For sufficiently large $n$, this is going to be better.

Comment: Thank you Michael Grant for developing my initial idea. I can see why it is incomplete: if for instance $\omega_1=1$, then the constraints are equivalent to $x+y=1$: the part $0\le x,y\le 1$ is missing! Your solution fixes this.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. The failure to fix $M$ is certainly an issue, especially since you *can* fix it (2 perhaps)? And it's not necessary to use the binary variables on the convex half of the problem. Still, I thought yours was OK, but I couldn't prove it to myself, so I re-derived it. But I voted yours up because you definitely have the idea right.

Comment: I am suddenly doubting about your solution: if $w_1=w_2=w_3=w_4=0$, then the problem is infeasible I believe, as the intersection of the four equalities is empty. Am I wrong? How about changing the last constraint to $w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4=3$ ?

Comment: It is true that the problem will be infeasible in that case. But that just means *the model won't select all four zeros*. Feasibility will *require* that at least one of the $w_i$ values is nonzero, so all I need to do is make sure that not all of them are.

Comment: Hmmm. The model won't select all four zeros if the objective function does not impose it. Otherwise, wouldn't it be more cautious to adjust the last constraint?

Comment: No. The variables $w_i$ that you just created can't be in the objective, because they weren't in the original model. So if the original model is feasible, then the new model *will* ensure that at least one $w_i$ is nonzero.

Comment: Oh I see. Tricky!

Comment: To be clear, your change wouldn't break anything, it just isn't necessary.